Natural extension of Gauss measure (continued fractions)
There's a Gauss measure on $[0,1]$ given by its density
$$f(x)=\frac 1{\ln 2} \frac{1}{1+x} $$
It's invariant under Gauss map $x\mapsto\big\{\frac 1 x\big\}$ which acts as a left shift if we describe point $x\in[0,1]$ as a continued fraction: $x=[0, a_1,a_2,...]$. There's a construction of  "natural extension" of this system: let's consider left shift on doubly infinite sequences $...,a_{-2},a_{-1},a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},...$ where $x=[0,a_1,a_2,...]\in[0,1], y=[0,a_0,a_{-1},...]\in[0,1]$. This left shift acts as $$T(x,y)=\bigg(\bigg\{\frac 1 x\bigg\}, \frac{1}{y+\big[\frac 1 x\big]}\bigg)$$
And we can consider shift-invariant measure, coinciding on cylinders with positive indexes with original Gauss measure. It seems well-known that this measure has density
$$\frac 1{\ln 2} \frac{1}{(1+xy)^2}$$
but I can't understand how it can be obtained - is it technical result or we can somehow notice that this is it? I found papers of Hitoshi Nakada "Metrical Theory for a Class of Continued Fraction Transformations and Their Natural Extensions" and "ON THE INVARIANT MEASURE FOR THE TRANSFORMATIONS ASSOCIATED WITH SOME REAL CONTINUED-FRACTIONS" [which supposed to be useful] (i liked the second one more) but I  didn't quite get it.
